# Object data source with business objects slow?

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, business-objects

In my project I have a page with some RDLC graphs. They used to run on some stored procedures and an xsd. I would pass a string of the ID's of my results should include to restrict my data set. I had to change this because I started running into the 1000 character limit on object data set parameters.

I updated my graphs to run on a list of business objects instead and it seems that the page loads significantly slower than before. By significantly slower I mean page loads take about a minute now.

Does anybody know if object data sources are known to run slow when pulling business objects? If not is there a good way to track down what exactly is causing the issue? I put break points in my method that actually retrieves the business objects before and after it gets them; that method doesn't seem to be the cause of the slowdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more testing and it seems that the dang thing just runs significantly slower when binding to business objects instead of a data table.

When I was binding my List< BusinessObject> to the ReportViewer the page took 1 minute 9 seconds to load.

When I had my business logic use the same function that returns the List and build a DataTable from the list with only the required columns for the report, then bound the DataTable to the report the page loads in 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using select *? If so try selecting each field individually if you aren't using the entire table. That will help a bit.

Comment: My business logic uses entity framework and the user filters to pull only the requested items out of the database which are then converted to business objects and returned in a list by the method that the ObjectDataSource calls.

Answer (score 0):

@William: I experienced the same problem. I noticed though, when I flatten the business object, the reports runs significantly faster. You don't even have to map the  business object to a new flattened one, you can simply set the nested object to null. I.e.:

```
  foreach(var employee in employees)
    {
        employee.Department = null;
        employee.Job = null;
    }
```

It seems that the reportwriter does some weired things traversing the object graph.

This seems to be the case only in VS 2010. VS 2008 doesn't seem to suffer the same problems.